Understanding expansion patterns related to \exp_args:Ne
I have read tens of pages on expansion, and for whatever reason, I am still missing a clear understanding. To help me understand, I would like to focus on a specific example.
Consider the following code (here the choice of \myfunction_core:n and \tl_tail:n are just for the illustration: they can be thought of as \outerfunction:n and \innerfunction:n)
\cs_new:Nn \myfunction_a:n{
    \exp_args:Ne \myfunction_core:n{\tl_tail:n{#1}}
}
\cs_new:Nn \myfunction_b:n{
    \myfunction_core:e{\tl_tail:n{#1}}
}
\cs_new:Nn \myfunction_core:n{
    % Do something here
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \myfunction_core:n{e}

My questions are the following:

QUESTION 1: Will \myfunction_a and \myfunction_b have the same behaviour for all inputs? If not, what is the difference?
QUESTION 2: When doing \exp_args:Ne \myfunction_core:n{\tl_tail:n{#1}}, #1 seem to be protected against expansion and forwarded as is. For example if #1 is equal to ab \mycommand cd, \myfunction_core seem to receive as an input b \mycommand cd (\mycommand not being expanded). Do I have the guarantee that when using the pattern \exp_args:Ne \outerfunction:n{\innerfunction:n{#1}}, #1 will never be expanded? Is there a way to look at it to understand why that is the case (for example by understanding how it is parsed)?
QUESTION 3: How would I do it if I wanted (it's not what I want, but let's mention it for the thought experiment) to expand everything (including #1)?
QUESTION 4: What would happen if I replace \exp_args:Ne by \exp_args:No, \exp_args:Nf, or \exp_args:Nx? (examples of an input #1 or another function instead of \tl_tail:n  for which the results would all be different would be super nice). In the case of \exp_args:No what is a pattern/situation in which it makes sense to use it instead of \exp_args:Ne?
QUESTION 5: Keeping the same pattern, is there a simple example that would illustrate the use of exp_not?


has anybody mentioned the one-question-per-question concept?

Some suggestions to enhance learning and understanding. First try and understand how TeX does things, as this is what is working behind the scenes. Read nd practice until you comfortable with all these: 1) delimited and undelimited defs 2) differences between def and edef, let expandafter etex's  expanded, unexpanded futurelet etc.  l3 is to a large extend is syntactic sugar and lots of convenience functions and vars.

Please do take account of the need for one query per post - a lot of this is covered elsewhere, and ideally we'd be able to point to specific duplicates

Tackling one at a a time:

Variant some \my_func:e is exactly equivalent to \exp_args:Ne \my_func:n - the reason for the use of variants is they make the flow clearer at a very slight performance cost (one extra expansion)

e-type expansion expands as far as possible - but many expl3 functions are written to ensure that the results are predictable despite this. Thus the documented behaviour of \tl_tail:n is that the result is wrapped in \exp_not:n, and thus is not expanded further. This allows output of exactly the 'tail' of a token list. However, that's not automatic - it's a decision made in writing \tl_tail:n and is documented for the function

To expand a result protected with \exp_not:n, you can add a second \exp_args:Ne (perhaps using an auxiliary, but could be done in-line), or define a version of the underlying function that does not use \exp_not:n

x-type expansion is deprecated other than very particular internal use inside expl3 - it's more-or-less equivalent to e-type anyway. Using o-type expansion carries out exactly one expansion, so you'd get the definition of \tl_tail:n with #1 substituted by your input.

\exp_not:n prevents expansion by e/x-type expansion - it does not prevent o-type expansion but that is rather dependent on where you put the o-type


\cs_set:Npn \aaa { aaa }
\cs_set:Npn \bbb { bbb }
\exp_args:Ne \tl_show:n { \exp_not:n { \aaa \bbb } \aaa \exp_not:n { \bbb } }

for example

Well, defacto \exp_not:n protects against a single step of o-type as well, but is consumed in the process :)

@Skillmon In the sense it's just \use:n under those circumstances, sure - but it's not really 'doing' anything

Also tackling one at a time, hopefully giving more/alternate versions to the existing answers.

It will behave equivalently, but using a generated variant saves token memory and is more concise at the expense of an additional expansion step (really miniscule performance hit). The convention was to use a variant on anything needed more than once, otherwise using \exp_args:N<type> for a one-off thing was considered fine. That convention has been altered, nowadays the general take on this is to use a generated variant in any case.

Functions in expl3 are documented how they return their value. In the case of \tl_tail:n (as with many other functions) the result is returned inside of \exp_not:n so is protected against further expansion. If you don't want to look at the source code the documentation (apart from trial and error) is the only place to get this information from. So no, there is no guarantee that this works for every function (but it does for quite some, as I said, check interface3, if you use third party expl3-code packages like gtl, etl, etc., the documentation should state this as well, but sometimes it might not).

The answer to this question depends on what you want to achieve. Is your goal to first expand #1, then have the internal function do its thing? In that case simply use \my_outer:e { \my_inner:e {#1} }. Is your goal to have the inner function do its thing and afterwards expand whatever it did return inside \exp_not:n? In that case use \exp_args:Ne \my_outer:e { \my_inner:n {#1} }. One of the main goals of expl3 is to make keeping track of expansion easier, I hope the above is self-explanatory to you.

As Joseph already stated x-type expansion is deprecated. The same is mostly true for f-type expansion, which has its useful edge cases but for many of its original applications e-type is mostly what you want (that didn't exist back when expl3 was created). However:

For x-type expansion \exp_not:n has the same effect as for e-type (see below for the difference of the two).
For o-type it behaves just as \use:n, so in a sense it indeed protects against it just like a prefixed \prg_do_nothing: or \use:n {#1} would, simply because its expansion is its argument outside of e- or x-type expansion.
\exp_not:n can't protect against f-type expansion (that's what \exp_stop_f: is for).

The situation in which you want to use o-type instead of e-type is exactly when you want to expand the first token of an input once. Situations in which this is useful is mostly for relatively low level code, let's just say you'll know when you meet it.

Well, \tl_tail:n is a good example of \exp_not:n and why you want to apply it. The operation necessary to make \tl_tail:n work is not that simple (and it was much more complicated in the past, before e-type expansion was added to the language), and can't work in a single step of expansion. So we use \exp_not:n to protect its return value and document it. That way users can use e-type expansion and rely on the correct result, without ever bothering how many steps of expansion are necessary for the inner workings of the function. Many of the expandable functions provided in expl3 have this behaviour, so most of them use \exp_not:n (those which don't mostly predate e-type expansion).



The differences between e- and x-type expansion are:

x-type can't work by expansion only, as it needs an assignment internally.
x-type needs you to double # tokens.

Implementation wise e-type expansion uses the \expanded primitive, while x-type uses an \edef.
